# Python Flask app on Ubuntu 16.04 (AWS ec2 instance) with Apache server

Tags: apache, flask

I have a simple python web app on AWS ec2 instance-Ubuntu 16.04 with the following structure: [image]
When I run the app using python3 only, it works BUT once I run it with Apache server, some python packages-pandas in this case fails to work. The error its producing is as below:[image]
I have tried redoing the whole thing but nothing seems to work. If there is anyone who has experienced a similar problem, please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually permissions. I was trying to read a csv file with pandas but apache didn't have the permissions to access the files. After some digging, I changed ownership of the directory which contains my app to 'www-data' which is the apache user and that solved the problem.